# How to Join an SQL Alchemy ORM Query Object with another Query or Table?

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, orm, presto

Using SQL Alchemy ORM with Athena database (PyAthena engine). I cannot seem to be able to join a Query object with another Table object based on one column. Here is the schema of the `Query` object and the `Table` object.

[image: Schema]

For each row of the query object, I need to find the corresponding *zone*. In SQL, this would look like

```sql
WITH query AS (-- The query defined 
)
SELECT start_dt, zone FROM query INNER JOIN addresses 

WHERE query.start_address_ref=addresses.address_ref;
```

This is what I am trying in SQL alchemy ORM after I formed the `query` object correctly.

```py
# I expect newquery to contain columns from the addresses table
newquery=query.join(target=addresses, 
    onclause=trip_table.columns[trip_address]==addresses.columns[address_ref])
```

But it seems when new-query is formed, it does not at all contain the columns from `addresses` table for me to find the zone id. In fact, the join statement seems not to have any effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need `.cte()` here is example from my project

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import Select

sub_query: Select = (
    select(
        TrackingEventDB.entity_id,
        func.min(TrackingEventDB.created_at).label("min_created_at"),
    )
    .where(
        *query_conditions,
    )
    .group_by(
        TrackingEventDB.entity_id,
    )
    .cte("min_dates")
)


q = (
    select(
        TrackingEventDB.company_id,
        TrackingEventDB.aircraft_id,
        TrackingEventDB.event,
        func.count(TrackingEventDB.id).label("count"),
    )
    .select_from(
        TrackingEventDB,
    )
    .join(
        sub_query,
        and_(
            TrackingEventDB.entity_id == sub_query.c.entity_id,
            TrackingEventDB.created_at == sub_query.c.min_created_at,
        ),
    )
)
```